# Firebase functions solution for building a secure Chat App with Seen functionality

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, chat

I am building a chat app using Flutter and Firebase.

The way it works in Firebase Firestore is really simple, I just have a conversationId which represents the documents where there are the messages, all of the users have a list of their conversations, when they tap on a conversation, a new screen pops up where they see the messages based on data from the stream of the "Messages" collection that is under the conversationId document. Basically that's the structure

```
col: Chats
    doc: conversationId
        col: Messages
              message documents...
```

And this is how I get the messages inside the Chat Screen.

```
_firestore
    .collection("Chats")
    .doc(_messageCollectionId)
    .collection("Messages")
    .orderBy("sentOn", descending: true)
    .snapshots()
    .map(...)
```

The message document is basically the message text and when it was sent and who sent it.

I want to create the "seen" functionality, inherently I want the user to see what conversation he read or not (which ones have new messages, like instagram chat or discord)

I can not come up with a good solution to this, my main 2 problems are:

1. If I were to call a cloud function which fetches the messages and somehow marks them as being read, that would break my app, as I need a continous stream of live message data for the chat to feel good, I can not stream data from the cloud function.
2. I would like to create a system which is not write intensive. If I would have to mark each message document in particular with some "seenOn :timestamp" value, that would mean that if the user is reading 200 new messages, there are 200 new writes on each document, which seems too much to me, there should be another way.

I am asking for guidance on how I should go about the architecture of such a chat using Firebase. Maybe my chat model is not really fit for what I need, how should I tweak it?

Another problem is that I do not know how the "seen" signal should be sent. If I manually write to a document and change the boolean value of some "isRead" field from my client, the client could easily skip that line of code and break my whole seen system, they could read messages without sending the seen signal just with a break point. This is quite exploitable, there is no cloud function trigger on documents "onRead" that could help me move that logic outside the client, so what is the solution to make this also secure?

Comment: you could use that your chat structure like that, but i prefer to create 2 collection

Comment: Why is that and how will that make it better? Can you send me a model or something about how 2 collections work?

Comment: I would be glad if you can direct me to some codelab or a tutorial on how to make a fully functioning chat app, with seen functionality. I was not able to find anything.

Comment: I think there's no tutorial that directs us to make a fully perfect function chat app, without using commercial API like agora or stream

Comment: Could maybe realtime database be better suited for such an intensive write and read heavy application?

Answer (score 3):

so if you want to create the seen function you could made the database structure look like this first
[image]

you should create 2 collection for the db, the users collection would only save user data and in the `chats` collection inside of the uid is saving the chat room id that would be look like this
[image]

that was the collection inside of users. only put the roomId of connection that been made when user trying to send a new message to other user. put the the field exactly look like that. after that you could create a chatroom collection that look like this[image]

to be sure that random uid inside of `chats` collection is a room id that you should register in your users/doc/chats/ collection. the field inside of the roomId would be a connection between of the 2 user for accesing the message that've been send to db. and inside of the `chat` collection you would send message data in this format
[image]

and after you put that you could retrieve the chat data using stream function that would look like this

```dart
 Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> streamChats(String chatId) {
    CollectionReference chats = firestore.collection("chats");
    return chats.doc(chatId).collection("chat").orderBy("time").snapshots();
  }
```

each time of user sending message you could put the total of message that've been send to other user in the total_unread field and update it when other of user open the chat roomId. and tada your seen could work properly

oh and you can create a function that check the total_unread is 0 already and you can put the seen/check icon beside of your user message bubble.

Comment: This seems reasonable, I would not have a field inside each message document "isRead" because I do not want to mass write to a lot of documents when the user suddenly reads 20 new messages, that is a problem I am trying to solve, isn't there any other way to do this that does not require a new field inside message documents? That is write intensive.
Another problem is that when the user opens the chat screen, how should the signal that the user read the message be sent? Changing it manually can be easily exploited, and there is no cloud function trigger "onRead" or something.

Comment: I edited my question to include the security part inside it.

Comment: i think there's no other way that i could make the seen function. work without updating the total_unread inside of the doc.

Comment: I do not mean about the total_unread, I said I would not like updating the "isRead" field on all message documents every time the user reads a new message, because if the user suddenly reads 10 meesages, that is 10 writes I have to do, and there is the problem of where do I perform those writes? Do I send them from the client, does the client decide what messages to "seen", cause this can be easily exploited and there would be too much trust in the client.

Comment: oh the isRead, hmmmmmmm i don't have any idea about other solutions that might work. but that all the best I can help